# How to troubleshoot a VPN connection drop

Tags: networking, windows-8, vpn, wireshark

I have a Windows 8 machine that won't connect to a work VPN (other machines configured the same* way work fine). The IT dept at work says the attempt never shows up in the logs. On my computer, it seems to connect and then suddenly drop that connection. No error messages show up, it just says its disconnected.

I used Wireshark to capture the an attempted connection on both the problem computer and a working computer. I'm not very good with raw network data (like Wireshark provides), but it seems to all work the same until an unexpected RST packed shuts the entire connection down. Can I use that data to somehow determine what's causing the unexpected RST and ultimately the problem? I would be happy to post the log, but I suspect they have sensitive security information in them...

System Details:

- Forigate SSL VPN with Forticlient on the client machine
- Windows 8, Asus ZenBook
- No certificate or PSK used in connection (user/pass only)
- Other VPNs / network services work fine on this computer

*"same" meaning I can't spot the difference, but obviously one works and one doesn't.